# Solidus gem showing error regarding ruby version during bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, rbenv

I am trying to install Solidus gem which is a fork of spree and while running `bundle install` this shows up

```
Installing solidus_core 1.1.0

Gem::InstallError: solidus_core requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing solidus_core (1.1.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
```

even when I am running ruby version 2.2.3

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

I am using rbenv on OS X El Capitan to control the ruby versions. Is there a problem with ruby version control or any other issue?

Comment: try setting your Ruby version explicitly in your Gemfile like so: `ruby '2.1.0'`

Comment: Try running it with `bundle exec bundle install` to make sure it uses the ruby version in the context of your current apps directory.

Comment: I tried setting `rails '2.2.3'` it gives that the ruby being used is `ruby '2.0.0'` so I think it must be some problem with `rbenv` usage. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Thanks, The problem was with my rails installation. I installed rails with `sudo` permissions which sent it to system directory and was using system version of ruby. Did a rails install without sudo and `rbenv rehash` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `ruby '2.2.3'` in Gemfile, and execute `bundle install`.

If it's not resolved, please check your bundle path to execute this:

```
$ which bundle
/usr/bin/bundle # global
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```